# Mongoose returning empty array after populate() method

Tags: typescript, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-populate

Banged my head against the wall for past 3-4 hours and checked countless articles here on StackOverflow but could not get my response to populate an array correctly. Using Express.js with Typescript, MongoDB and mongoose. Issue is when I get a response with all the orders my orderedlines array is empty even though I can check and see the ids are there in [MongoDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgCtv.png) atlas. Here is the actual response:

```json
[
  {
    "orderedlines": [],
    "_id": "6251c61f7385c349f88fe95a",
    "userId": {
      "favourites": [
        "623b39e684b9baf1109053f8",
        "623b3afada0e7828602c78df",
        "623b3b49da0e7828602c78e7",
        "623b39ba84b9baf1109053f7",
        "623b3b59da0e7828602c78e9"
      ],
      "_id": "62326179b9c85d3fc833d686",
      "orders": [],
      "email": "testche_emailche@gmail.com",
      "username": "stef1222",
      "password": "$2b$10$3e5Y/IoyrcJHH3ud6Mn/I.8PfBm2JrEKHwYRd8cQwUaAdz.YkKSMa",
      "firstName": "Stefan",
      "lastName": "Georgiev",
      "image": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dtggdx3hc/image/upload/v1648046254/deqr4chfysogoppafdug.png",
      "isAdmin": false,
      "hasWriteAccess": false,
      "__v": 0
    },
    "totalPrice": 121.99,
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

As seen above my userId is being populated successfully with all its properties but orderedlines is failing to populate and it is returned as empty array. If I remove the .populate() it returns an array of objects with ids

My findOrdersForUserId function in orderServices where I assume the problem occurs

```js
const findOrdersForUserId = async (
  userId: string
): Promise<OrderDocument[]> => {
  const ordersToReturn = await Order.find({ userId: userId })
    .sort({ _id: 1 })
    .populate('userId')
    .populate({path:'orderedlines', model:OrderLine})
  return ordersToReturn
}
```

Here is my Order model:

```js
import mongoose, { Document } from 'mongoose'

export type OrderLine = {
  orderlineId: string
}

export type OrderDocument = Document & {
  userId: string
  orderedlines: OrderLine[]
  totalPrice: number
}

const orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  userId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true },
  totalPrice: Number,
  orderedlines: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'OrderLine',
    },
  ],
})

export default mongoose.model<OrderDocument>('Order', orderSchema, 'orders')
```

My OrderLine model:

```js
import mongoose, { Document } from 'mongoose'

export type OrderLineDocument = Document & {
  productId: string
  userId: string
  quantity: number
  price: number
}

const orderLineSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  quantity: { type: Number, default: 1 },
  price: Number,
  productId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Product',
    required: true,
  },
  userId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: true,
  },
})

export default mongoose.model<OrderLineDocument>('OrderLine', orderLineSchema, 'orderlines')
```

```
Mongoose version used: mongoose@5.13.10
Node version: v16.13.0
Mongo Shell version: v5.0.6
Express version: express@4.17.1
```

I would list some of the articles I tried to fix my the issue without success:

1. [Mongoose populate returning empty array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38658227/mongoose-populate-returning-empty-array)
2. [Mongoose populate() returning empty array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30600292/mongoose-populate-returning-empty-array)
3. [Mongoose populate() returns empty array with no errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39005072/mongoose-populate-returns-empty-array-with-no-errors)
4. [Mongoose Populate not working with Array of ObjectIds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40012717/mongoose-populate-not-working-with-array-of-objectids)
5. [Populate method not populating my comment array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61817983/populate-method-not-populating-my-comment-array)
6. [Mongoose populate does not populate array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52012778/mongoose-populate-does-not-populate-array)
7. [Mongoose populate not populating an array and always returns an empty array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62330574/mongoose-populate-not-populating-an-array-and-always-returns-an-empty-array)

Edit: All the code is a part of a fork from a repo that is set to private. I am not sure how can I share access/link to the fork for a better preview of the code. Please enlighten me if you would like to see something else or a more specific part of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question because I struggled with this a lot and want to help future people reading this question.
First of all and really important issue might be if you are not specificying a collection name. In order to specify a collection name add a third argument in your model creation like so:

```
export default mongoose.model<OrderLineDocument>('OrderLine',orderLineSchema,'orderLines')
```

Before the third argument mongoose was creating a collection name with a **lower-cased plurarized** model name - orderlines. But when I was trying to populate my response I was referring to orderLines with a capital L. So heads up always specify your collection name **or** check your collection name in your MongoDB Shell/ MongoDB Atlas.

Second of all. Always check if the _ids your array/object that you want to populate are **correct** _ids that exist in your [database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0yTH.png). If they are non-existent or wrong the response would either contain empty array or even would return error.

For example I was adding this in the beginning when the error was occuring but those _ids were not existing (I had deleted them before but forgot) in my orderLines collection in the first place (you can still add _ids that are not existing if they are the correct _id structure so be aware)

```
POST http://localhost:5000/api/v1/orders/62326179b9c85d3fc833d686
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "orderedlines":[
      {"_id": "6251be4d4186c34788e4f034"},
      {"_id": "6251be494186c34788e4f030"}
  ],
  "totalPrice":"121.99"
}
```

Third of all. If you are using TypeScript there are three approaches that work:

1. Using your own type

```
export type OrderLine = {
  _id: string
}

export type OrderDocument = Document & {
  userId: string
  orderedlines: OrderLine[],
  totalPrice: number
}
```

2. Saying this would be an array of string

```
export type OrderDocument = Document & {
  userId: string
  orderedlines: string[],
  totalPrice: number
}
```

3. Array of ObjectIds

```
export type OrderDocument = Document & {
  userId: string
  orderedlines: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId[]
  totalPrice: number
}
```

After all of the above three things are taken in consideration what worked for me in the end was this approach:

```
const findOrdersForUserId = async (
  userId: string
): Promise<OrderDocument[]> => {
  const ordersToReturn = await Order.find({ userId: userId })
    .sort({ _id: 1 })
    .populate('userId')
    .populate({
      path: 'orderedlines',
      populate: { path: 'productId', model: 'Product' },
    })
  return ordersToReturn
}
```

And this is a **part** of the response I am getting just to showcase that both orderedline, productId and userId are being populated correctly

```
{
        "quantity": 4, //part of a single orderedline object
        "_id": "6251be494186c34788e4f030", //part of a single orderedline object
        "productId": { // beginning of populated productId
          "_id": "623b3b24da0e7828602c78e3",
          "name": "AMY SS14R - TRICKSTER",
          "image": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dtggdx3hc/image/upload/v1648048425/amy-deluxe-stick-steel-r-ss09r10_1000x1000_bfngtl.jpg",
          "price": 1299,
          "__v": 0
        }, // end of populated productId
        "price": 2.99, //part of a single orderedline object
        "__v": 0 //part of a single orderedline object
      }
    ], // end of the orderedline array of objects
    "_id": "6252bfa8dd00081d7c273e4d", // _id of the order
    "userId": { //beginning of populated userId
      "favourites": [
        "623b39e684b9baf1109053f8",
        "623b3afada0e7828602c78df",
        "623b3b49da0e7828602c78e7",
        "623b39ba84b9baf1109053f7",
        "623b3b59da0e7828602c78e9"
      ],
```

Answer (score 0):

You defined `OrderLine` like this:

```js
export type OrderLine = {
  orderlineId: string
}
```

Then, you specified `orderedlines` as an array of `OrderLine`:

```js
orderedlines: OrderLine[]
```

In your use case, `orderedlines` are an array of `ObjectId` and not an array of objects with nested property `orderlineId`. TypeScript probably do some sort of casting when defining a model.

Try to change `orderedlines` to be an array of `ObjectId` and try again?

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work in this case also. Same [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lA9rS.png)

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you try it again?

Comment: Yes the issue was actually located there but I did need to update the type of orderLineId but the actual name. The issue went away when I changed OrderLineId to _id in my OrderLine type like [so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usJS4.png). Now I am facing a similar issue trying to populate a nested property productId in my orderedlines.... Any suggestions there also?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same outcome. My issue was, when I "Post"/create the object. I did the regular

```
const orderLine = new OrderLine({object})
```

but I forgot to

```
await orderLine.save()
```

check your post.