Mongoose populate not returning the desired data neither an error to identify the problem
I have the followings models:
The article one:
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const articlesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    isFixed: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    author: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Users',
    },
    comments: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Comment',
        },
    ],
    updatedAt: { type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now },
    views: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    likes: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    body: { type: String, required: true },
    images: { type: Array, required: true },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Article', articlesSchema);


and the comments that the users can leave in each article created.
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    article: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Article',
        required: true,
    },
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true,
    },
    body: { type: String, required: true },
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Comment', commentSchema);

However when using the fuction to populate the article with its comments no error ocurrs but no comments are returned, even though being present in the mongoDB. I've tried to analyse many times but couldnt find the reason why the comments array length is 0(no comments). Even tried to use ChatGPT to check the code and it says that the code seems right. Do you guys have any suggestions? Even blog posts talking about this "relational part" would be very useful. But if you have some time to check the code and see if it is really okay i would be very grateful!
Function to populate:
async function getArticle(id) {
        const article = await Articles.findOne({ _id: id })
            .populate([
                {
                    path: 'author',
                    select: 'username isAdmin -_id',
                },
                {
                    path: 'comments',
                    select: '_id',
                },
            ])
            .exec();
        return article;

}


Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71816519/2282634

In your articles collection, does each document actually have an array of ObjectIds that correspond to the _id of a valid comment from the comments collection? It's a common misconception that mongoose will do this for you but you have to manually add ObjectIds into the article.comments array so that they can be used in the populate process. Post a sample Article document into your question please.

@jQueeny Thx for the tip! It worked right after I manually added a comments array(via mongoDB atlas), than I use this code to make it automatically after the comment creation:
const article = await Articles.findById({ _id: articleID });
article.comments.push(newComment._id);
await article.save();
One last doubt... Is this the recommended approach to do this? Thank you one more time...

That looks perfectly fine. You can use findByIdAndUpdate which will do it in one database call as opposed to findById followed by save which is two database calls but either way is fine.
